# Had a problem with the special charactered url when opening with in the application

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am trying to open an url with in the application. It has some special characters like, ./_ =| | #. It is not opened when I try to open it with in the application like [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneUrl]]; but it is not responding. When I Pasted the url in safari of simulator it is working fine. I don't know where the problem is. Can you guys please help on this.

Thanks in Advance.
Sekhar

Answer (score 0):

Try to add percent escapes for characters illegal in URLs:

```
NSString* escapedPhoneUrl = [phoneUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:escapedPhoneUrl]];
```

Comment: @ Valdimir:    
Thanks for the quick reply.But I had a problem when using 
                    
NSString* escapedPhoneUrl = [phoneUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF*StringEncoding];

but it is throwing some 2 errors like,

1. 'NSUTF' undeclared.
2. 'StringEncoding' undeclared.

Comment: @ Vlaidmir: it is working fine when I used NSUTF8StringEncoding.